# readLines taking up too much storage

Tags: r, readlines

I'm using `readLines` to read in a bunch of very large .csvs with a ; delimiter using the below code:

```
read_p <- function(flnm) {
  readLines(flnm)  %>%  str_split(pattern = "; ") 
}

for (i in 1:length(files)){
  dat[[i]] <- read_p(files[[i]])
}
```

Where `files` is a vector of filenames. The code itself runs fairly quickly, but it takes up around 4GB in R, whereas it only takes up ~500MB in the folder - is there something I missed in reading it in to avoid?
I need to use readLines as there are no headers (so its not really a csv) and each line has a different length/number of columns.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operating off of `test.csv` from your previous (since deleted) question, there can be a stark difference after conversion to `numeric`.

For the record, the file looks like

```
996; 1160.32; 1774.51; 4321.05; 2530.97; 2817.63; 1796.18; ...
1008; 1774.51; 1796.18; 1192.42; 1285.69; 1225.96; 2229.92; ...
1020; 1796.18; 1285.69; 711.67; 1761.44; 1016.74; 1671.90; ...
1032; 1285.69; 1761.44; 1016.74; 1671.90; 725.51; 2466.49; ...
1044; 1761.44; 1016.74; 725.51; 2466.49; 661.82; 1378.85; ...
1056; 1761.44; 1016.74; 2466.49; 661.82; 1378.85; 972.94; ...
1068; 2466.49; 661.82; 1378.85; 972.94; 2259.46; 3648.49; ...
1080; 2466.49; 1378.85; 972.94; 2259.46; 1287.72; 1074.63; ...
```

though the real `test.csv` has 751 lines of text, and each line has between 10001-10017 `;`-delimited fields. This (unabridged) file is just under 64 MiB.

Reading it in, parsing it, and then converting to numbers has a dramatic effect on its object sizes:

```r
object.size(aa1 <- readLines("test.csv"))
# Warning in readLines("test.csv") :
#   incomplete final line found on 'test.csv'
# 67063368 bytes

object.size(aa2 <- strsplit(aa1, "[; ]+"))
# 476021832 bytes

object.size(aa3 <- lapply(aa2, as.numeric))
# 60171040 bytes
```

and we end up with:

```r
length(aa3)
# [1] 751

str(aa3[1:4])
# List of 4
#  $ : num [1:10006] 996 1160 1775 4321 2531 ...
#  $ : num [1:10008] 1008 1775 1796 1192 1286 ...
#  $ : num [1:10009] 1020 1796 1286 712 1761 ...
#  $ : num [1:10012] 1032 1286 1761 1017 1672 ...
```

So reading it in into full-length strings isn't what explodes the memory, it's splitting it into 10000+ fields per line that does you in. This is because there's a larger overhead *per `character` object*:

```r
### vec-1, nchar-0
object.size("")
# 112 bytes

### vec-5, nchar-0
object.size(c("","","","",""))
# 152 bytes

### vec-5, nchar-10
object.size(c("aaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaa"))
# 160 bytes
```

If we look at the original data, we'll see this exploding:

```r
object.size(aa1[1])   # whole lines at a time, so one line is 10000+ characters
# 89312 bytes
object.size(aa2[[1]]) # vector of 10000+ strings, each between 3-8 characters
# 633160 bytes
```

But fortunately, numbers are much smaller in memory:

```r
object.size(1)
# 56 bytes
object.size(c(1,2,3,4,5))
# 96 bytes
```

and it scales much better. Obviously, enough better to reduce the data from 453MiB (split, strings) to 57MiB (split, numbers) in R's storage.

---

You will still see a bloom in R's memory usage when reading in these files. You can try to reduce it by converting to numbers immediately after `strsplit`; to be honest, I don't know how quickly R's garbage collector (a common thing for high-level programming languages) will return the memory, nor am I certain how this will behave in light of R's [*"global string pool"*](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html). But if you are interested, you can try this adaptation of your function.

```r
func <- function(path) {
  aa1 <- readLines(path)
  aa2 <- lapply(aa1, function(st) as.numeric(strsplit(st, "[; ]+")[[1]]))
  aa2
}
```

(I make no promises that it will not still "bloom" your memory usage, but perhaps it's a little less-bad.)

And then the canonical replacement for your `for` loop (though that loop is fine), is

```r
dat <- lapply(files, func)
```

Comment: Hi @r2evans, thanks so much for your extensive answer. You're absolutely right , what was truly taking up the storage was storing the numerics as characters rather than the actual readLines function. using your code, `lapply(aa1, function(st) as.numeric(strsplit(st, "[; ]+")[[1]]))` was markedly faster. Also worth noting for anyone curious that the for loop seems to be more stable in memory usage than lapply in this case, but that may be chalked up to working from a dropbox folder.